# Groovy compiler phase with variable resolution

Tags: groovy, compilation

I am creating a custom `CompilationUnit` with the intention to compile some Groovy script only up until a specific phase.

I want to have variables resolution inclusive so I am compiling up to the `SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS` phase.

```
CompilationUnit cu = new CompilationUnit(compilerConfiguration);
File file = new File("scripts/script12.esc");
cu.addSource(file);
cu.compile(Phases.SEMANTIC_ANAYLSIS);
```

My test script is really simple and has this content:

```
def a = b + "c";
```

The `compilerConfiguration` is nothing special except for the fact that I have the Type checking extension enabled.

And here comes the problem: as type checking is enabled, I would assume that Groovy will try to resolve the variables in the script. And this should happen during the SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS phase. But running this does not provide the expected errors.

If I let it compile up to the INSTRUCTION_SELECTION phase, then I get (as expected) `[Static type checking] - The variable [b] is undeclared.` But this happens a bit too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The `@TypeChecked` annotation actually is a kind of AST tranformation which runs during the INSTRUCTION_SELECTION phase - so no wonder that it did not run during SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS.